# how to fix undefined data from json data?

Tags: json

I have JSON data like this `{"id":"27","kode":"1111","judul":"q","penulis":"q","penerbit":"q","tahun_terbit":"1","tgl_masuk":"2017-08-09","tgl_update":"2017-08-09"}`

How to display id? I try with `data[0].id`, `data['id']` or `data.id` and the result remains `undefined`. Thanks for the answers

Comment: which language  you re using ?

Comment: I use jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse your `string JSON` into an `Object`

```
var str = '{"id":"27","kode":"1111","judul":"q","penulis":"q","penerbit":"q","tahun_terbit":"1","tgl_masuk":"2017-08-09","tgl_update":"2017-08-09"}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( str );
```

then you can :

```
console.log(obj.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the language is javascript, here we go:

```js
var data = {"id":"27","kode":"1111","judul":"q","penulis":"q","penerbit":"q","tahun_terbit":"1","tgl_masuk":"2017-08-09","tgl_update":"2017-08-09"};

console.log(data.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is JavaScript, and since you've referred to "data" in your question, your statement might look like this:

```
var data = {"id":"27","kode":"1111","judul":"q","penulis":"q","penerbit":"q","tahun_terbit":"1","tgl_masuk":"2017-08-09","tgl_update":"2017-08-09"}
```

If so, you can access the "id" property like this

```
alert(data.id);
```